# Do composite indexes improve performance?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Say I have a composite index like:

```
- kind: Order
  properties:
  - name: active
  - name: email
  - name: shipped
```

I have a query that uses Order like

```
Order.all().filter('active', True).filter('email', email).filter('shipped', True)
```

From looking at the documentation it appears that the index is unnecessary and can be safely removed because the simple indexes on those properties can fulfill the query.

Is there any benefit to having this composite query? Does it improve the lookup speed or reduce the number of datastore reads?

Answer (score 1):

My experimental evidence suggests *yes*, there can be significant speedups from such a composite index.

Without the composite index, datastore will need to make 3 intermediate queries (one for each filter condition) and then merge the results. If these intermediate result sets are large, this can result in significant degradation of performance.

I describe my experience here:
[Firestore in Datastore mode: index hotspots for enum property values vs. just poor indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383441/firestore-in-datastore-mode-index-hotspots-for-enum-property-values-vs-just-po/59473233?noredirect=1#comment105373662_59473233)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, off course the above indexes improve performance. 
The correct synatx is : `Order.all().filter('active =', True).filter('email =', email).filter('shipped =', True)`